# Обработка нажатия клавиш в консоли Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, консоль

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой командой в консоли проверить нажатие клавиши, но чтобы при этом это нажатие не требовалось. Т.е. getch() не подойдет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [_kbhit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/58w7c94c(v=VS.100).aspx).

```
#include <conio.h>

while (true)
{
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        _getch();
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, то, что надо 

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool KEY[256];
void GetKEY()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 256)
    {
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(i)) KEY[i] = 1; else KEY[i] = 0;
    i++;
    }
}


int main()
{

//Оброботка

while(1)
{
GetKEY();
    if(KEY[13]) //нажат ентер
    {
        cout<<"ENtrer"<<endl;
    }
    else
    if(KEY[32]) //нажат пробел
    {
        cout<<"Sp...";
    }
    Sleep(10);
}

}
```