# Остановка цикла при нажатии определённой клавиши

Tags: c

Условия: происходит безостановочный цикл, при нажатии клавиши Enter(13) он останавливается.

Я думаю, задачка легчайшая, просто я не знаю необходимой функции. getch не подходит (как я понимаю), т.к. он требует обязательного нажатия после каждого цикла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то вроде такого:

```
#include <conio.h>

while (true)
    if (_kbhit())
        if (_getch() == '\r')
            break;
```

Похожий вопрос - [там](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/705/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-visual-c).

Comment: Извиняюсь и благодарю)